# Replacement for Jacuzzi tub faucet with both handles on one side

Tags: faucet, bathtub, bathroom-fixtures

Our Jacuzzi tub faucet has both hot & cold controls on the same side. I am looking to replace it, but cannot seem to find anything like it on the net. Everything I see has the controls on either sides of the faucet & the plumber says that would not work. Does this type of faucet assembly have a special name? Where should I look?

[image]

Pipes underneath the spout & hot/cold knobs:

[image: Pipes underneath the spout & hot/cold knobs]

Comment: Please clarify why you are replacing? Are you wanting a different finish/style?, or is there something wrong with the current faucet? If so what part failed?   Asking to see if current might just need parts.   Have you tried a plumbing supply house or Jaccuzzi dealer?

Comment: What's strange about that? Lots of hot and cold knobs are right next to each other.    Usually the spigot is not next to the faucet, it's nearby usally under it to some degree.   Usually the spigot is mounted on the tub proper and the knobs are above it.  That is to say, the spigot is not part of the valve.     Also, it's time to upgrade to a temperature control valve that can't scald you.

Comment: The spout is connected to the hot and cold valves with tubing or hoses. It could have been placed in a different location; in fact I would bet it could have been placed where that vent is, and the vent off to the right, where it would look more traditional to you (and more like the replacement faucets you have been looking at). Get a new plumber?

Comment: @Tyson We have remodeled our bathroom and changed the other brass fixtures (most pretty worn out) with brushed nickel fixtures. I did try a few different stores - Home Depot, Lowes, Hot tub store - but they didn't have something like this.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Thanks for your answer. I have uploaded a picture with the pipes underneath the spout & the valves. It does seem to me that we need a set of a certain type (spout - knob- knob), but I am a newbie so could be completely wrong about this.

Comment: Assuming it's Jacuzzi branded (as opposed to generic use of the word Jacuzzi) I would suggest going to Jacuzzi.com and using the "find a showroom" feature to locate a local dealer in your area.  Big box store won't have something like this.

Comment: @Tyson I did, but the one here in Minnesota just carries parts for free-standing hot tubs, not the installed ones in bathrooms :-(

Comment: Did you use the "bath" showroom locator: http://www.jacuzzi.com/baths/find-a-showroom/ if so, pick a large city like Chicago or San Fransico instead and try calling a dealer there.

Comment: Any plumber can do different set up or modification , adjustment to fit customers desires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting... the original plumber piped that up him/herself (looks like good work BTW). Generally speaking, faucets for your application are typically plumbed in with flexible connections. The components are separate (hot valve, cold valve, spout) just like yours was prior to being hard plumbed. The faucet does not care either way!

Any regular Roman Tub faucet set should work for you. I would recommend flexible stainless connectors if your city inspector allows it (due to vibration from tub pump/blower). Sometimes flex is disallowed due to limited access, but this is an interpretation by the inspector and your's looks accessible to me.

This will involve "unplumbing" your faucet (I just made that word up and I officially claim it).